# Mirror ImageView for RTL-Language?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, xcode12

How can i mirror a play button image when the language is RTL. I can't find a appropriate option in the `Storyboard` menu in Xcode 12.

Comment: You can use `myImage.ImageFlippedForRighToLeftDirection` but actually here in Israel we use a left facing play button image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `image.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()` method which returns flipped image if current language is RTL(right to left) and then change the imageView's image to it.

**Swift**

```
playButton.imageView?.image = playButton.imageView?.image?.imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection()
```